# Cordova, Ajax, error en apk build

Tags: android-studio, ajax, cordova

tengo un problema que ya me tiene desesperado,
Estoy creando un app y cuando lo intento "buildear" con Android Studio SKD el apk generado no me realiza las llamadas Ajax, leí sobre el uso de las whitelists, la meta tag de protección y configuré todo a pie de letra, aún así no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Mi config y meta tag son:

```html
<access origin="http://myserver.com" />
<access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="https://maps.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://ssl.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

<!-- and my meta tag -->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://myserver.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

Por otro lado les comento que al crear el apk desde build.phonegap.com ahí no hay problema con esto.

Alguien sabe la solución a esto?

Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué servidor estás haciendo la llamada AJAX?

Comment: A un server mío que tiene access origin * y acepta métodos GET, POST, PUT.

Comment: Cabe destacar que cuando hago test desde phonegap en mí celular no tengo este problema, tampoco lo tengo al levantar la versión browser del app, solo al generar el apk descargable. Además como dije, si hago la build desde build.phonegap.. no tengo problema.